# How to map previous/next buttons of my dell mouse on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: mouse, dell, 17.10, xinput, mouse-pointer

the previous/next buttons of my dell mouse do not work on ubuntu 17.10. Other buttons are working fine.

According to [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto), I tried to perform button remapping using `xinput list` and then `xinput test #device-number`

Here is the ouput of `xinput list`:

```
ben@precision ~ $ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:14                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:14              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:14                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to run  `xinput test 2`,`xinput test 4`, etc... and then click mouse buttons to identify my device number but this has no effect, nothing printed to the output.

How can I identify my mouse device and then perform lateral buttons mapping?

Answer (score 2):

Your mouse is probably id=6 on that list. It ought to work with `xinput test 6` or `xinput test xwayland-pointer:14`. On my machine, this only works when the mouse is over the root window (i.e., over the desktop, not over an application window).

On my Dell mouse, the previous/next buttons are 8 and 9 instead of 6 and 7. I can fix this with `xinput --set-button-map <dev num> 1 2 3 4 5 8 9` (with `<dev num>` the id number in the output of `xinput --list`, i.e., 6).

Also, your system is now running its events through wayland, which is hiding the actual devices from you. That is why you see the xwayland-pointer, etc, instead of the actual device names. I have not yet sorted this out, but I think installing libinput-tools and using `libinput debug-events` is the preferred way to go. However, I can't find a way to fix this other than xinput.

Comment: You explanation of how to use xinput test worked for me. You could improve the command like this: xinput test 6 | grep button. I also have a Dell mouse, previous/next buttons are 8 and 9, but they don't work. How did you make them work?